# How to have different parts of config file in c#

Tags: c#, configuration-files

what I am trying to do is for my App.config file i have a bunch of settings, and what i want to do split up my config file into different files. For example; my app.config file file has setting pertaining to emails, so i want to take those settings out and store it in an email.config file and then in my app.config file use the configSource attribute to add thos settings from the email.config file and add it to the app settings node. Is this possible?

If so please advice on how to acheive the above result.

Many thanks.

so for example i have another config file called app1.config and has the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings >
    <add key="l" value="test"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and then from my main app.config file have a reference to the app1.config file and then from code be able to do this to get the value of the app setting key:

```
 var x = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["l"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT to reflect changed question and additional comments:**

For custom settings defined in the `<appSettings>` part of the config file there is a `file` attribute that can contain the path to a file that overrides the appSettings parameters:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8818/Using-the-File-attribute-of-the-appSettings-elemen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings file="settings.config">
 </appSettings>
</configuration>`
```

You can indeed also use the configSource attribute, as specified in the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

> The ConfigSource property represents the value of the configSource attribute that is specified for a ConfigurationSection object that is associated with the SectionInformation object.
>
> A ConfigurationSection implementation can optionally specify a separate file in which the configuration settings for that section are defined. This can be useful in multiple ways:
>
> Using include files can result in a more logical and modular structure for configuration files.
>
> File-access security and permissions can be used to restrict access to sections of configuration settings.
>
> Settings in an include file that are not used during application initialization can be modified and reloaded without requiring an application restart.
>
> The following example shows how this attribute is used in a configuration file to specify that the pages section is defined in an external include file:
>
> `<pages configSource="pages.config"/>`

Or, if you want to store info from the same section in separate files, you can always revert to using the ConfigurationManager.Open...Configuration functions and read the settings programatically:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134262.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I have tried this, but im not getting the value, its coming back as null. Here is my external config file called App1.config, and only contains :
<appSettings >
  <add key="d" value="test"/>
</appSettings>

and my main configs app settings section that looks like this:
<appSettings file="App1.config">
    <add key="test1" value="4"/>
    <add key="test2" value="400"/>
    <add key="test3" value="10"/>
</appSettings>

and on my code behind i am doing this:

var x = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["d"];

but it is getting null and not the value.

Please assists. is advance

Comment: Okay thanks alot for this this has worked! :)

But can I specify multiple external config files?

If so, could you please advise on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tried it again and it works for me, are you sure that the file App1.config is in place (same directory as the program)? For a console program for instance this means you have to set the 'Copy to Output Directory' setting to 'Copy always'

Comment: Yip it works for me now, I had to set the 'Copy to Output Directory' setting to copy always. But now i would like to have multiple external config files and reference all of them from the main config file. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes and No; you can use custom config sections, but will have to set up some code to be able to read them. And in any case the rule  is always one file per section. Or you can store multiple app.config files as independent settings files and read those from code by using the ConfigurationManager.Open...Configuration functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built in configuration section for [smtp settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.smtpsection.aspx) in a file of its own:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

This can be referenced in your `app.config` using `configSource`.

You can limit this to the `smtp` section alone, if you want:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configSource="smtp.config" />
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the email was just an example. I need to split it up for anything and then just reference it from the app.config file.

Comment: @johnnie - If the settings are defined in a config section, you can do that. If not, you can always write your own config sections for your particular usage and use them. This is not difficult, as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the `configSource` attribute:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <connectionStrings configSource="cs.config" />
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

ConfigSource maps an entire section to an external file. Once you've added it, you can't use the section in the root config file anymore. neither can you have more than one mapping per section.

You could create a custom config section, as suggested above, with the sections you want to map & then map each section in turn.

web.config:

```
<myConfig>
    <mysection1 file="section1.config"/>
    <mysection2 file="section2.config"/>
</myConfig>
```

section1.config:

```
<mysection1>
    <add key="key1" value="val1"/>
</mysection1>
```